# SQL Inner join into counting distinct

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

I have three tables: 
 Customer
- Region
- Carrier

I need to find out how many customers each carrier has.

```
select CarrierFirstName + ' ' + carrierlastname ' Carrier Name', CustomerID
from Carrier
inner join Route ON Carrier.CarrierID = Route.CarrierId
inner join Customer ON Customer.RouteID = Route.RouteID
group by carrier.CarrierFirstName, CarrierLastName, CustomerID
```

This gives me carrier names several times and each distinct customerID, whereas i need names followed by the TOTAL number of customers associated with each name

```
Joe Johnson | 15|
Carrie Lan  | 12|
```

Comment: Hi. (Obviously,) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the `group by`.  This also uses table aliases to simplify the query:

```
select (c.CarrierFirstName + ' ' + c.carrierlastname) as carrier_name,
       count(*)
from Carrier c inner join
     Route r
     on c.CarrierID = r.CarrierId inner join
     Customer cu
     on cu.RouteID = r.RouteID
group by c.CarrierFirstName, c.CarrierLastName
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you just need to take the count here:

```
SELECT
    CarrierFirstName + ' ' + carrierlastname AS 'Carrier Name',
    COUNT(*) AS num_customeres
FROM Carrier ca
INNER JOIN Route r
    ON ca.CarrierID = r.CarrierId
INNER JOIN Customer cu
    ON cu.RouteID = r.RouteID
GROUP BY
    CarrierFirstName + ' ' + carrierlastname;
```

Note that it is not desirable to aggregate the carriers by their names, because two people can have the same first and last name (I even have a double somewhere in the world).  Instead, aggregating by some primary key in the `Carrier` table would be a better strategy.

I introduced aliases into the query to make it easier to read.